# The fastest way to build .NET Web Project in Visual Studio 2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, build

I am working on .NET Solution that has multiple projects inside. One of the projects is ASP.NET Web Application that I am currently working on. Very seldom I have to build the whole project. Mostly I just want to build my web application and test it in the browser.

What would be the fastest way to do this?

I am sort of tired of navigating my Solution Explorer, finding my web project, right click then build.

I would like to be able to issue command (in command window or command prompt) and to assigne shortcut to this command. Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the solution and configure Batch Build... or as @Nico suggests, use msbuild directly.

See [Batch Build Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/169az28z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `msbuild /m <your project>` which build your thread with  more worker threads to finish your build.  It will also run it with multiple process, which should improve execution speed as well.

See Also: [MSBuild Command Line Reference (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)